# Asp.Net Mocking a Repository that returns a DbSet with .GetAll().ToListAsync()

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, moq

In my ASP.Net application I have a controller I'd like to unit test. Here's some relevant code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserController(IUserRepository repo, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userRepository = repo;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _userRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync());
    }
```

I want to test the Index()-method, so I create a DummyDbContext using https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable to help mock the repository.

Relevant code:

```
public class DummyDbContext
{
    private ICollection<User> _users;
    public Mock<DbSet<User>> _dbsetUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return _users.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
        }
    }

    public DummyDbContext()
    {
        _users= new List<User>();

        _users.Add(new User("Alan"));
        _users.Add(new User("Claire"));
        _users.Add(new User("Paul"));
        _users.Add(new User("John"));
    }
```

In my test-class I proceed as follows:

```
public class UserControllerTest
{
    private readonly DummyDbContext _context;
    private readonly Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>> _userManager;
    private readonly Mock<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> _signInManager;
    private readonly Mock<IUserRepository> _userRepository;
    private readonly UserController _controller;

    public UserControllerTest()
    {
        _context = new DummyDbContext();
        _userManager = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(
                new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>().Object,
                new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                new Mock<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>().Object,
                new IUserValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
                new IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
                new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object);
        _signInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>(
            _userManager.Object,
            new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().Object,
            new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>>().Object,
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object,
            new Mock<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object);
        _userRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        _controller = new UserController(_userRepository.Object, _userManager.Object, _signInManager.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void Index_GetModelContainingAllUsers()
    {
        _userRepository.Setup(g => g.GetAll()).Returns(_context._dbsetUsers.Object);
        var actionResult = await _controller.Index() as Task<ViewResult>;
        var usersResult = actionResult?.Result?.Model as IEnumerable<User>;
        foreach (var g in usersResult) {
            Console.WriteLine(g.Username);
        }
        Assert.Equal(4, usersResult.Count());
    }
```

**Now, the problem is that usersResult is null. And I can't figure out why; have I done something wrong doing the setup for userRepository?**

Frankly, I feel like I'm doing something wrong having to write all of this code just for something that should be a simple mock.

Comment: You could test the lines you want to test directly in your test first. Then you could split the calls up to two lines and debug the test.

Comment: Why you don't use in memory database?

Comment: @Nikolaus: I'm not sure what you mean, you mean splitting up the ToAsyncList and the GetAll calls?

Comment: @H. Herzl: how would I go about doing that? Frankly I thought the DummyDbContext was exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem.

The issue was that I was casting the result of _controller.Index() as Task whereas I should have been casting it as ViewResult instead. When the Task is complete ("await"), I receive a ViewResult that gets assigned to actionResult. By casting it as Task I was getting null.

Here's what it should have read:

```
 [Fact]
    public async void Index_GetModelContainingAllUsers()
    {
        _userRepository.Setup(g => g.GetAll()).Returns(_context._dbsetUsers.Object);
        var actionResult = await _controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        var usersResult = actionResult?.Model as IEnumerable<User>;
        Assert.Equal(4, usersResult.Count());
    }
```

Comment: Makes sense as awaiting the Task returns the ViewResult. But the not alone the user-result was null as you asked.